# Como crear una rule para filtrar correos electrónicos inválidos en laravel

Tags: laravel, regex

```
class emailValido implements Rule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value){

      $email_filter =>'regex:/^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/';

      if($email_filter ?? $value){
           return true;
      }else{return false;}

    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Email invalido';
    }
```

1. no se como testear el regex con la variable.
   2)el regex me tira una señal de error.

"En la documentación no vi nada de esto así que no estoy seguro si se puede usar regex en un archivo rule" "mi versión de laravel es la ^8"

Comment: Laravel ya trae una regla para validar emails: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `passes()` es el que dice si el valor que recibes pasará o no la validación, en tu caso, si quieres comparar el valor que te envían con una expresión regular, entonces debes hacer lo siguiente, haciendo uso de [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php):

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match('/^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/', $value);
}
```

Comment: Barato corto y bonito... gracias L.Flor